# Identify false In-App iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

We have a game on the AppStore that offers In-App, in out server we are detecting all the in-apps that the users make. But now we are detecting like 20-30 in-app per day that doesn't pay for it, we double check our code if the code that update our server execute in wrong screens, and the code its correct.

So I start searching and I found that there its a way to get free in-app with cydia, so I want to know if there is a way to detect if that in-app its genuine? I think I can't get the in-app ID from apple, but I don't know that if someone buy with a hack they get a ID for the in-app?

This is messing up all our DB because we don't know if the sells of our users are genuine or not, also after getting apple report I can't detect which of all the in-app are real and which aren't

Minimum I want to know in my server which one are real and which ones not

Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't this be reported to Apple?

Comment: @Pekka웃 even if Eduardo reported it to Apple, apple can do nothing about it as users are using jailbroken devices and Cydia. Welcome to wild wild world of app and software hacking.

Comment: I also send a mail to apple, still no response, but I think they know. What I think it's that this works for all the in-app of apple no only our app. When the users try to connect to apple they mount a local server and response success buy to the app. Similar to adobe key hack. @Pekka웃

Comment: @Sam well, forged in-app purchases sound like something major that *they* should be fixing. (If there is a way to verify as vborra suggests, though, then that seems to be the way to go)

Comment: Hi @SamBudda, I know :P but I want a way to detect it minimum for my own statistics :S

Comment: @Eduardo right, I see. Interesting.

Comment: @EduardoIglesias if all else fails and you are losing too much money on these fake in-apps then make your app a paid app and turn off in-apps completely. price of freemium Vs paid ... and paid apps do sell.

Comment: @SamBudda I really don't care about how much money I am losing, my main problem is that I want to track my users that buy something, But I can't because a few users get free stuff. And it's a fermium game can't make it paid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can verify your receipt with apple. See the following link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html

Comment: Verifying the receipt is the way to go :]

Comment: “Merely validating a receipt against Apple is not enough,” - read http://www.macworld.com/article/1167677/hacker_exploits_ios_flaw_for_free_in_app_purchases.html. someone who wants to hack ... most likely already knows a way around this

Comment: @SamBudda, Interesting, and theres not a server in-app validation? I validate from my own server?

Comment: Apple has long since fixed that bug and validating the receipt is what Apple still recommends.

Comment: When you say "Apple has long since fixed that bug..." do you have a source? As far as I've ever know, most IAP hacks were done by DNS and SSL swizzles, which is why external validation is necessary.

Comment: See the following article, http://gizmodo.com/5928186/free-in+app-purchases-hack-will-be-dead-in-ios-6 It is fixed as of iOS 6. See the following documentation for iOS 5.1 and Earlier: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/StoreKit/IAP_ReceiptValidation/